# How to disable all clickable items in AppBarLayout?

Tags: android, android-view

I'm trying to disable all `clickable` items in the `app bar layout` when the opaque background appears after clicking the `floating action button`. But I also need to make sure that all the `floating action buttons` are all still clickable. I'm thinking maybe I can disable all items in the app bar programmatically?

How to achieve this?

[image]

**UPDATE**
Code to set fab visibility and animation. When the Fabs displayed, the tabs and toolbar finally disabled and unclickable. But i want to make my Fabs still clickable. How can i do this? Please advice. Thank you!

```
public void fabVisibility(){
        if (isOpen){
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
            fabActivity.startAnimation(fabClose);
            textViewActivities.startAnimation(fabClose);
            fabPost.startAnimation(fabClose);
            textViewPosts.startAnimation(fabClose);
            fabMedia.startAnimation(fabClose);
            textViewMedia.startAnimation(fabClose);
            fabPlus.startAnimation(fabRotateAntiClockwise);
            fabActivity.setClickable(false);
            fabPost.setClickable(false);
            fabMedia.setClickable(false);
            shadowView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            isOpen = false;
        }else {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
            fabActivity.startAnimation(fabOpen);
            textViewActivities.startAnimation(fabOpen);
            fabPost.startAnimation(fabOpen);
            textViewPosts.startAnimation(fabOpen);
            fabMedia.startAnimation(fabOpen);
            textViewMedia.startAnimation(fabOpen);
            fabPlus.startAnimation(fabRotateClockwise);
            fabPlus.setEnabled(true);
            fabActivity.setClickable(true);
            fabActivity.setEnabled(true);
            fabPost.setClickable(true);
            fabPost.setEnabled(true);
            fabMedia.setClickable(true);
            fabMedia.setEnabled(true);
            shadowView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isOpen = true;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the user interaction you just need to add the following code

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

To get user interaction back you just need to add the following code

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Comment: I've tried using this one. But even tha FAB cannot be clicked anymore. How can i exclude my FABs?

Comment: If in that case use [FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(getActivity());
    fab.setEnabled(true);]

Comment: I've updated my question and applied your suggestion but it still didn't work. Is there any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To disable action bar (app bar) buttons on clicking FAB icon, you could set a flag, let's say `DisableAppBarButton`. 
Now call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` which will trigger `onCreateOptionsMenu` and will regenerate your menu.
Modify your `onCreateOptionsMenu` to disable the buttons.

```
if (DisableAppBarButton) {
    menu.someItem(R.id.yourItem).setEnabled(false);
} else {
    menu.someItem(R.id.yourItem).setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1 - You can set a view group to be disabled by recursively setting all of its children disabled. Example:

```
public static setEnabled(View view, boolean enabled) {
  view.setEnabled(enabled);
  if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
      setEnabled(viewGroup.getChild(i), enabled);
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your code in response to the FAB showing or hiding:

```
ViewUtil.setEnabled(mAppBarLayout, true /* or false */);
```

2 - You can make the opaque background focusable and clickable to intercept clicks while it's overlayed over the app bar, while the FAB buttons that float above that background would still receive clicks.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm trying to the no 2 solution. Ive set the view as focusable and clickable as false. And when i click fab plus, the view will display. But it still didnt work. I still managed to click and swipe tab. Any ideas why?

Comment: You're supposed to set the background's clickable and focusable  to `true`, not `false`.

Comment: Yup. You're right. My mistake over there. Thank you for the help!